# Floating right doesn't move element to right side in a flexbox

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.background-image {
  background-image: url("https://solscan.io/static/media/banner-header-1.c1e47687b38c8afc4f948ebd7004acf8.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  height: clamp(150px, 15vh, 20vh);
  width: 100vw;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: - 1;
}

.nav-bar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 1.2rem 0.8rem;
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  /* margin-left: auto; */
}

i {
  font-size: 29px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <title>Page title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="background-image"></div>
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <img src="https://solscan.io/static/media/logo-solana-scan.ae03f445fd27dddc90c859d8728cbb44.svg">
      <div class="logo">
        <!-- <img src="sol.svg"> -->
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

I wanted to float class logo to right side of flexbox using float right but it's not actually moving from the place and I cannot find the reason why would be good if anyone could explain me the reason.

I used `margin-left: auto;` to push the div to right side but I still need to learn the reason why float didn't work.

Comment: use justify content end

Comment: @DeveloperNans thanks for answering but I want to know the reason why float right didn't work!

Comment: @DeveloperNans no I am still waiting for the reason you would provide I can't figure and Justify-content:end didn't work too

Comment: Do you want the logo.svg in center

Comment: @DeveloperNans check the code I have included urls for image, I want the font awesome logo (i tag) at the right side

Comment: I am talking about the SVG file if you want that left side and class logo to the right side then  just add `justify-content: space-between` in the class navbar

Comment: @DeveloperNans it worked but my question still is why didn't float: right work?

Comment: display flex doesn't support float you have to use display inline or inline block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.nav-bar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 1.2rem 0.8rem;
  display: flex;
justify-content: space-between
}
```